# Wxpython Phoenix - Multiple OnDropFiles boxes with TABS

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I have a python 3 (wxpython phoenix) app which has two TABs, each TAB has a OnDropFiles box, but I just can't get it working. I have a simple stripped down example below, which should print the file URL on each drop, but not working, if someone could show a working example please, or point me in the right direcion, I would be very gratefull.
I'm using Python 3.10.5 and wxpython 4.2.

```
import wx

class ScrolledWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(510, 330), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER |
                                                wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))

        run_params = {}
        self.tabbed = wx.Notebook(self, -1, style=(wx.NB_TOP))
        self.filePrep = PrepFile(self.tabbed, self, run_params)
        self.fileCheck = CheckFile(self.tabbed, self, run_params)

        self.tabbed.AddPage(self.filePrep, "File Prep")
        self.tabbed.AddPage(self.fileCheck, "File Check")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED, self.switchSize)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def switchSize(self, e):
        page = self.tabbed.GetPageText(self.tabbed.GetSelection())
        if page == 'File Prep':
            self.SetSize((510, 330))
        elif page == 'File Check':
            self.SetSize((510, 510))
            self.fileCheck.setSubmissionDrop(self)

class PrepFile(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, frame, run_params):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.run_params = run_params
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = self
        self.selectedFiles = ""

        outputtxt3 = '''Drag and Drop files'''
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, outputtxt3, pos=(25, 180), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

        self.drop_target = MyFileDropTarget(self)
        self.SetDropTarget(self.drop_target)
        self.tc_files = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, pos=(28, 200), size=(360, 25))
        self.tc_files.SetFocus()
        self.Show()

    def setSubmissionDrop(self, dropFiles):
        """Called by the FileDropTarget when files are dropped"""
        print(dropFiles)
        self.tc_files.SetValue(','.join(dropFiles))
        self.selectedFiles = dropFiles

class CheckFile(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, frame, run_params):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.run_params = run_params
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = self
        self.selectedFiles = ""

        wx.StaticText(self, -1, '''Drag and Drop files''', pos=(25, 10), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

        self.drop_target = MyFileDropTarget(self)
        self.SetDropTarget(self.drop_target)
        self.tc_files = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, pos=(25, 30), size=(302, 25))

        self.tc_files.SetFocus()
        self.Show()

    def setSubmissionDrop(self, dropFiles):
        """Called by the FileDropTarget when files are dropped"""
        print(dropFiles)
        self.selectedFiles = dropFiles


class MyFileDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    """"""
    def __init__(self, window):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.window = window

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        print(filenames)
        self.window.setSubmissionDrop(filenames)
        return True

app = wx.App()
ScrolledWindow(None, -1, 'File Prep ')
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

We want this to be `event` driven, so you should define an event, from `wx.lib.newevent`.
I assume you want the drop zone to be the textctrl not the whole panel, so it's that that needs to be set as the target.
`BIND` the event.
In the `FileDropTarget` class we define the `event` and fire it.
In each drop event callback, we accept the event as a parameter and unpack whatever we packed into the event.
One last thing, in this case, you are getting back a `list`.

It's simple but every time you decide to use it, it trips you up, I don't know why.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.newevent
drop_event, EVT_DROP_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class ScrolledWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(510, 330), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER |
                                                wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))

        run_params = {}
        self.tabbed = wx.Notebook(self, -1, style=(wx.NB_TOP))
        self.filePrep = PrepFile(self.tabbed, self, run_params)
        self.fileCheck = CheckFile(self.tabbed, self, run_params)

        self.tabbed.AddPage(self.filePrep, "File Prep")
        self.tabbed.AddPage(self.fileCheck, "File Check")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED, self.switchSize)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def switchSize(self, e):
        page = self.tabbed.GetPageText(self.tabbed.GetSelection())
        if page == 'File Prep':
            self.SetSize((510, 330))
        elif page == 'File Check':
            self.SetSize((510, 510))

class PrepFile(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, frame, run_params):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.run_params = run_params
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = self
        self.selectedFiles = ""

        outputtxt3 = '''Drag and Drop files'''
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, outputtxt3, pos=(25, 180), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.tc_files = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, pos=(28, 200), size=(360, 25))
        self.drop_target = MyFileDropTarget(self)
        self.tc_files.SetDropTarget(self.drop_target)
        self.Bind(EVT_DROP_EVENT, self.setSubmissionDrop)
        self.tc_files.SetFocus()
        self.Show()

    def setSubmissionDrop(self, event):
        """Called by the FileDropTarget when files are dropped"""
        files = event.data
        print("\nprep event", files)
        self.tc_files.SetValue(','.join(files))
        self.selectedFiles = files

class CheckFile(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, frame, run_params):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.run_params = run_params
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = self
        self.selectedFiles = ""

        wx.StaticText(self, -1, '''Drag and Drop files''', pos=(25, 10), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.tc_files = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, pos=(25, 30), size=(302, 25))
        self.drop_target = MyFileDropTarget(self)
        self.tc_files.SetDropTarget(self.drop_target)
        self.Bind(EVT_DROP_EVENT, self.setSubmissionDrop)
        self.tc_files.SetFocus()
        self.Show()

    def setSubmissionDrop(self, event):
        """Called by the FileDropTarget when files are dropped"""
        files = event.data
        print("\ncheck event", files)
        self.tc_files.SetValue(','.join(files))
        self.selectedFiles = files



class MyFileDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):
    """"""
    def __init__(self, window):
        wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.obj = window

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
        drp_evt = drop_event(data=filenames)
        wx.PostEvent(self.obj, drp_evt)
        return True

app = wx.App()
ScrolledWindow(None, -1, 'File Prep ')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks Rolf, but using your example, when I drop a file in, either TAB, nothing is printed. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @speedyrazor Are you using my code from my example or are you using your adaptation of it, Try running it direct from the command line. Ensure you drop onto the textctrl. I've just tried it here (Linux python 3.8 wxpython 4.1.1 gtk3) and it's fine.

Comment: Im using your exmaple code, copied and paisted, im on Mac, Pycharm, Python 3.10, WXPython 4.2

Comment: @speedyrazor In that case I'm not sure. It seems there's been trouble with MacOs and wxwidgets before with regard to DragandDrop see: https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/drag-and-drop-within-wxtreectrl-on-macos/34790/16 best check your version of wxwidgets as opposed to wxPython. p.s. I've tried changing the droptarget to the tab with `self.SetDropTarget(self.drop_target)` and that works too.

Comment: @speedyrazor See: https://wiki.wxpython.org/Optimizing%20for%20Mac%20OS%20X

Comment: Thanks @Rolf of Saxony, I think you are correct, as my original code came from a working python 2.7, wxpython 2.8. So looks like there is an issue in the current version for Mac. Thanks for your help.